# Is it possible to iterate over a FileSystemObject SubFolders collection by index?

Tags: vbscript

I understand that it's possible to iterate over SubFolders using a For Each loop, as follows:

```
for each f in myfolder.SubFolders
    WScript.Echo f.ShortName
next
```

However, I would like to iterate by index. I can't seem to get it to work, nor find any examples online. This is what I have tried:

```
for i = 1 to myfolder.SubFolders.Count
    WScript.Echo myfolder.SubFolders.Item(i).ShortName
next
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT

Here is the use case:

For at least one of my subfolders, I get a Permission Denied error which happens on the for each line. As such I need to wrap the whole for loop in error handling:

```
on error resume next
for each f in folderobj.SubFolders
    ' do some stuff
next
on error goto 0
```

What I want to do is finer grained more controlled error handling, like this:

```
for i = 0 to folderobj.SubFolders.Count - 1
    on error resume next
    ' access folder
    if Err.Number = RELEVANT_ERROR_NUMBER then
        ' do something sensible
    end if
next
```

Comment: No it doesn't support accessing the collection by index `Item()` only accepts a key which in this case is the file path. Why would you want to access it by ordinal index, what does that give you that `For Each` approach doesn't? Just trying to understand your motivation for wanting this behaviour.

Comment: @Lankymart, thanks. I am getting a Permission Denied error on the for each line for one of the subfolders. I want to put the error handing code within the for loop, rather than trying to wrap the whole for loop in error handling code.

Comment: I'm still not sure why you think an index `For` loop will facilitate that over a `For Each`?

Comment: @Lankymart, I've added an edit to the original post to explain further. Perhaps you've got a suggestion of how to best error handle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Lankymart already pointed out the [`Folders`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcx47hd%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) collection returned by the [`SubFolders`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1dthkks%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property doesn't allow access by index, only by name. If you need indexed access you will have to put the folder objects into an array first:

```
ReDim sf(myfolder.SubFolders.Count - 1)
i = 0
For Each f In myfolder.SubFolders
  Set sf(i) = f
  i = i + 1
Next
```

Then you can access the elements in `sf` by index.

```
For i = 0 To UBound(sf)
  WScript.Echo sf(i).ShortName
Next
```

Note that VBScript arrays are zero-based, so the index will run from 0 to `.SubFolders.Count-1`.

Note also that if anything changes the collection you must re-synchronize the array with the collection yourself. It won't pick up changes automagically.

Comment: Still what’s the point in doing this? I know it can be done and could have left an answer, just don't see any merit in doing it. If there was it would have been included by Microsoft in the first place.